# How do I prove a convolution is a polynomial?

Tags: real-analysis

I have a problem with the following question:

> $f$ is a continuous function and $f=0$ when $x\notin [0,1]$.
>
> $(g_n)=x^n$  when $-1<x<1$ and $0$ else.
>
> Show that $(f*g_n)$ is a polynomial when $0\le t \le 1$.

I have no idea how to approach this question.

Comment: Are there any other contraints to $f$ other than ${\rm supp}(f) \subset [0,1]$ and $f\in C^0(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: no there no constraints

Comment: What does "continuous function $\,-0\;$ " mean?

Comment: Perhaps mention $t$ elsewhere in the sentence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By definition
$$f*g_n(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g_n(t-x)f(x)\ dx=\int_0^1 g_n(t-x)f(x)\ dx\ .$$
When $t\in[0,1]$ and $x\in\ ]0,1[\ $ then $\ t-x\in\ ]{-1},1[\ $, and therefore $g_n(t-x)=(t-x)^n$. It follows that for $0\leq t\leq1$ one has
$$\eqalign{f*g(t)&=\int_0^1 (t-x)^n f(x)\ dx\cr &=\int_0^1 \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} t^k(-x)^{n-k} f(x)\ dx\cr &=\sum_{k=0}^n c_k\> t^k\cr}$$
with
$$c_k:=(-1)^{n-k}{n\choose k}\int_0^1 x^{n-k}f(x)\ dx\ .$$

Comment: I don't understand the part you went from integration to sum.

Comment: @nadiazona It is an application of the Binomial Theorem.